# How to check Ubuntu program coredump in either bash or python?

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, coredump

I have a binary foo, and i will give a file input to foo which may potentially trigger coredump in Ubuntu. I write a loop to do so and I change the file content in every iteration. But I would like to terminate the loop whenever a coredump appears. Here is the bash code:

```
while true
do
  change_file file_s > file_new
  ./foo file_new
  # need to check coredump to terminate the loop
done
```

I can change the script to python if it is easier to do that in python.

Comment: Will `foo` ever return nonzero for non-core-dump reasons?

Answer (score 1):

If the return code is greater than 127, then the program exited due to a signal. Core dumps only happen as the result of this sort of exit.

```
./foo file_new
if (($? > 127)); then
    echo foo crashed
    break
fi
```